# comparing string in C# vs a static Regex?

Tags: c#, regex, string

I was wondering, is there any easy way for those who are really unfamiliar with regex to find out how to match a string with the regex format for the specified string?

For example, this string, which is generated from another function i have:

3A5AE0F4-EB22-434E-80C2-273E315CD1B0

I have no clue what so ever what the proper regex for this string is.

Lets say i had a function taking this string as a parameter

```
        public static bool isValidRegex(string inputString)
        {
            Regex myRegex = ????

            if inputstring matches myRegex then
            return true;

            else 
            return false;


        }
```

What would the Regex be to make this function return true?

NOTE: As i am unfamiliar with C# the code provided may not be correct at all, and i am aware.

Comment: Well, a string is not quite enough to construct a reliable regex. You need to define the rules. It seems your string uses hexadecimal digits, has 5 groups separated by `-`. Is the length of the groups fixed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this case, it looks like this is a Guid - if you're using .NET 4, the simplest approach is probably to use [`Guid.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.tryparse.aspx)... but if you need to use a regex, it would probably be:

```
^[0-9A-F]{8}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{12}$
```

In other words, start of string, 8 hex digits, dash, 4 hex digits, dash, 4 hex digits, dash, 4 hex digits, dash, 12 hex digits, end of string. Note that I've *assumed* any alphabetic characters will be upper case rather than lower.

It's probably worth creating this just once, and possibly compiling it, so you'd end up with:

```
private static readonly Regex GuidPattern = new Regex
    ("^[0-9A-F]{8}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{12}$",
      RegexOptions.Compiled);

public static bool IsValidRegex(string inputString)
{
    return GuidPattern.IsMatch(inputString);
}
```

Comment: Whoa, thanks. This has to be the fastest and best answer i've had on stackoverflow. Thanks!

Comment: Note: On versions of .Net older than 4, you still test this without using your own `Regex` by using `Guid`'s `string` constructor and checking for exceptions.  Obviously `TryParse` is much cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

if the format is 8 letters - 4 - 4 - 4 - 12

then it is

[0-9A-Z]{8}-[0-9A-Z]{4}-[0-9A-Z]{4}-[0-9A-Z]{4}-[0-9A-Z]{12}

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:

```
^[0-9A-Z]{8}-[0-9A-Z]{4}[0-9A-Z]{4}[0-9A-Z]{4}[0-9A-Z]{12}$
```

Between the curly braces you have the number of the elements, and between the [] you have all possible numbers an letters.

Answer (score 0):

Regex is a way of matching an exact value to a pattern. But you need to know what sort of pattern you will accept. In the example you quote what provides an acceptable match?

"3A5AE0F4-EB22-434E-80C2-273E315CD1B0" is the exact value

Would you be happy if someone passsed in "3A5AE0F4-EB22-434E-80C2-273E315CD1B1" 
or "xxxxxxxx-EB22-434E-80C2-273E315CD1B0"

or "xxx"

or 3.14257

etc.

So that's the first thing and it's determined by your requirements which you haven't made clear.

Then

```
 string sPattern = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$";
 bool match = Regex.IsMatch(yourstring, sPattern, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

will return true if your string contains only alphanumeric characters